# How to say "Automation parts supplier" in a broader way?

Tags: word-choice, phrase-choice

I need a more general term that could refer to any type of product that is sold to factories. This could include raw materials, machinery, equipment, and parts.

I came up with a few terms but I don't which one is correct and I want to make sure that there is no slang. I also want to make it sound native.

Should I say Provider of factory supplies or sourcing factory supplies?

Also, should I make the word factory singular or plural like Provider of factories supplies?

Should I put an apostrophe after the word factory/factories?

Thank you so much,

Comment: This is too general.  It is like asking "a word for a person who buys things in shops" or "a person that eats food".  Almost any company that supplies products could supply them  to a "factory".  This is just a "supplier".

Comment: You could certainly say you're a [***Components** Supplier.*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22a+Components+Supplier%22) That wouldn't include "complete / finished products" like computer printers, though.

Answer (score 1):

"Factory" itself is comfortable modifying another noun, like "factory workers." I'd just say "Factory parts supplier."

Answer (score 1):

If there is just one supplier you will be dealing with in a contract, you can use general terms, such as "factory parts supplier" Andy has suggested.  However, if there are several parties, you should be specific and state, for example, "raw material supplier", "machine parts/components supplier", and so on.  We do not need the apostrophe in any of the above.

If the "machine supplier" need to coordinate with an "electrical contractor", you should include also the latter term in your work specifications.

Terms that are too general won't be of much use.